# What happens when there are multiple Read requests to the same address in AXI3/4? Does RVALID assert each time?

Tags: digital-logic, bus, soc, interconnect, axi

Basically the title.  I am trying to do a verification on an AXI4Lite protocol.  If I try to send a read request to the same address multiple times the RVALID is not re-asserted.  Correct data just remains on the RDATA channel.

Sidebar question:  Assume 32-bit address width and 32-bit data width.  Do I need to be writing to address locations that are 4 locations apart (e.g. 0x00000000, 0x00000004...)?

Comment: Does the below response answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Yea, for every address transaction, you must be getting `RDATA`, `RRESP`, and `RVALID` asserted from the slave, even if it is the same address. You have to acknowledge each read-data by asserting `RREADY`.

If 32-bit byte-addressable slave, addresses are typically expected to be aligned as `0x0`, `0x4`, `0x8`... Some slaves support non-aligned addresses. Some don't...For instance: they would simply mask the least significant 2 bits and return the full 32-bit data at `0x0`, even if you request data at `0x2` for example... This is implementation specific.